# ioutil.ReadAll leads to goroutine leak

Tags: go, goroutine

Why do I have more than one goroutine before termination, even though I closed `resp.body`, while I only used blocking calls? If I do not consume `resp.Body` it terminates with only one goroutine.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func fetch() {
    client := http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * 10}
    url := "http://example.com"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    _, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("#Goroutines:", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    fetch()
    // runtime.GC()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    fmt.Println("#Goroutines:", runtime.NumGoroutine())
}
```

Outputs:

```
#Goroutines: 1
#Goroutines: 3
```

Comment: `ReadAll` does not dispatch any goroutines, so it's not possible that it's leaking any.

Comment: @JimB Yeah, I suspected that but removing `ReadAll`, but keeping `client.Do`, led to termination with one goroutine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default http transport [maintains a connection pool](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper).

> DefaultTransport is the default implementation of Transport and is used by DefaultClient. It establishes network connections as needed and caches them for reuse by subsequent calls.

Each connection is managed by at least one goroutine. This is not a leak though, you are just impatient. If you wait long enough, you will see that the connection is closed eventually and the goroutine goes away. The default idle timeout is 90 seconds.

If you want to close connections asap, set either of [http.Request.Close](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) or [http.Transport.DisableKeepAlives](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) to true.

Comment: @Peter, Thanks. I wrongly suspected `ioutil.ReadAll` as removing it would terminate with one goroutine. Why would consuming the body only lead to this?

Comment: @NimaMohammadi: if you don't read the body, then the connection can't be reused, so it has to be dropped.